# error while creating ArrayList of multiple datatypes

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb

This code connects Mongodb and Mysql database. There are two fields in mysql table `thing(String)` and `qty(int)`. I want to display in the same format like string and int in mongodb by creating an object class called Names which has string and int as field members and then use it ArrayList. I am getting a bug at line number 93 and 94(in the method `sqldbRead stock_list.add(....)`) as I am not using the perfect format I guess or may be there is some different error in the code. Couldn't figure this out for hours. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thank you.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;



public class connect {

// this opens and inserts data into SQL database, takes columns variables( string, int)

public  void sqldbInsert(String thing, int qty) throws ClassNotFoundException{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Creating a connection");
    try{      
        Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","Testuser",""); 
        System.out.println("Getting access to the database...");

     }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e.getErrorCode()+" :"+e.getSQLState()+" :"+e.getMessage());

        if(e.getErrorCode()==1049){

            //create database here with its own try catch block
            try{
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/","Testuser",""); 
                Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();                 
                 String sql = "CREATE DATABASE test";
                 stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                 System.out.println("Database created successfully");

            } catch(SQLException e1){
                System.err.println(e1.getErrorCode()+" :"+e1.getSQLState()+" :"+e1.getMessage());

            }

            try{
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","Testuser","");
                System.out.println("Inserting values into the table");

                PreparedStatement stmt =  con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DETAILS (thing,qty)VALUES(?,?)");
                stmt.setString(1, thing);
                stmt.setInt(2, qty);

                stmt.executeUpdate();
                stmt.close();
                con.close();

                 System.out.println("It's working!!");
                }

                catch(SQLException e1){
                    e1.printStackTrace();

            }  
        }   
    }

}


// also open , and reads the sql table, using specific select statement using qty field 
public  void sqldbRead() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    // open, sql select, and close 
    //returns array of objects

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","Testuser","");
    PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("select thing,qty from things where qty > 4");

    ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();


    ArrayList<Names> stock_list = new ArrayList<Names>();
    while(result.next()){

        stock_list.add(result.getString(1));
        stock_list.add(result.getInt(2));
     }
        Names[] stockArr = new Names[stock_list.size()];

        for(Names s : stockArr)
            System.out.println(s);

             mongodbInsert(stockArr);
            con.close();
}

// open mongo db, gets a array of objects, and inserts as  Field:value pairs
public void mongodbInsert(Names[]s){

// open, insert collection into a known collection, close

    try{   

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );


        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "First" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
    try{
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("begin");
        System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

         for(int i=0;i<s.length-1;i++){
                  BasicDBObject doc =  new BasicDBObject().append(s[i].toString(),s[i+1]);

                  coll.insert(doc); 
                  i++;
             }  
         System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.print(e.getMessage()+"Collection not found");
    }

}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.print(e.getMessage()+"Not connected to the database");

 }

}

 // read out specific mongodb document, takes string , int ( fieldname:value)    
public void mongodbRead(){
    // open, find, close
    try{
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "First" );
     System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");
     try{
        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("begin");
        System.out.println("Collection created successfully");

    Set<String> colls = db.getCollectionNames();

    for (String s1 : colls) {
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

    BasicDBObject whereQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    whereQuery.put("chair", "11");
    DBCursor cursor = coll.find(whereQuery);
    while(cursor.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(cursor.next());
    }
     }
     catch(Exception e){             
         System.err.print(e.getMessage()+"Collection not found");            
     }
} catch(Exception e){
    System.err.print(e.getMessage()+"Not connected to the database");

}    

} 
public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    connect conn = new connect();

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string and a value to insert into the database");
    String s = scan.next();
    int i = scan.nextInt();

    conn.sqldbInsert(s,i);
    conn.sqldbRead();
    conn.mongodbRead();
}

}
```

and the Names class is  :

```
public class Names {

    private int qty;
    private String name;

    public Names(int qty, String name) {
        this.qty = qty;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return this.qty;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What the error is would help...  There are no line numbers to match up against.

Answer (score 0):

stock_list.add() needs a Names Object, you are passing a String and an Integer.
Try

```
stock_list.add(new Names(result.getInt(), result.getString()); // give result.x() the right parameters
```

also you will have a bug in the next lines as where you create a new Array, but then you leave it empty and go for a

```
for(Names s : stockArr)
```

here stockArr has got the right size, but it is empty

```
for(Names s : stock_list)
```

this could work or before you go to the loop you can call the array function on the list    I cant check on it right now but i think it was something like

```
stock_list.toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you Neso for your reply. After Using stock_list.add(new Names(result.getInt(), result.getString()); as u have said it is free from error from this line but I am getting stuck in displaying the output and passing the value to the mongodb. I have added   stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr); so now it looks like Names[] stockArr = new Names[stock_list.size()];
   
   stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr);
  
   for(Names s : stockArr)
       System.out.println(s);
   
        mongodbInsert(stockArr);
          con.close();

Comment: nono  dont do stockArr = stock_list.toArray() because i dont know what it returns, but it modifies the array you put in as the parameter. If it returns an Array it will not be the same object as before (can be wrong because i dont know it atm but i will look in it now :D)            edit: I have looked t up and it seems that it returns an array filled with the content of the collection so i will chekc your code again =)

Comment: Yes the toArray wont work as it converts it again to array. Any possible suggestions? :/

Comment: Okay  you need to override the toString() method in Names and return a String that represents what you want to output

Comment: Please set a breakpoint at the loop and check if the array has got the right content. Also remove the "stockArr ="  and just use stock_list(stockArr). In the documentation you can read up the description of the parameter -> "the array into which the elements of this collection are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose." <- so maybe you only get the right array if you give it too much data.

Comment: there is no toString() method in Names .. :/ can you be explain me which part of code you want me to change please bro?

Comment: go to Names and create a method called :____ public String toString() ____ but ignore the ____   for the code kill || stockArr = stock_list.toArray(stockArr) || and replace it with || stock_list.toArray(stockArr) ||

Comment: But I don't want to convert all to String. I want to display the string as well as the int in the mongodb.

Comment: first to the mod -> I can not open a chat because of the reputation    okay  toString() will not "convert" your Object. It is a inherited method (you can find it in the class Object which all your classes bases on) and calling system.out.println() on your Names Object will call this method to show the String you want  if you dont override it you will not get your String and int displayed. You should add getter methods for your int and string in your Names class so you can call them in your mongodb

Comment: you can also flip this and leave all as it is  then create a public String getName() and a public int getQty()     then print them out using system.out.println("Name: " + stockArr[i].getName() +" qty: " + stockArr[i].getQty();

Comment: Thanks a lot Neso. Will try to implement all of these :)

Comment: let me knwo if it worked =) and if yes then choose this answer as the solution :D

Comment: Hi Neso , finnally I did it. altering alot . Did it in a different way. If you wanna see it I can post the whole code. didn't do any change in Names class. :)

Comment: ahh  okay   conratz :D   if you run into more problems just post them :D